# Prevent mouseLeave event when clicking login suggestions

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a dropdown menu that disappears on mouseleave after a couple of seconds.

The menu contains a login form that works well, apart from when you try to use a 'suggested' login/password from your browser's keychain.

When you try to select a suggested login, the page thinks this is a 'mouseleave' event and shuts the menu. Is there a way to prevent this from happening?

This is the basic layout of my menu:

```
<nav> 
 <a class="hover-link">Hover Link</a>
 <div class="dropdown">
   <form class="login-form">
     login form
   </form>
 </div> 
</nav>
```

and the jQuery

```
function hideMenu() {
  setTimeout(function () {
      $('.dropdown').css("display", "none");
  }, 300);
}

$(".dropdown").mouseLeave(hideMenu);
```

Here is a picture of what I mean by browser suggestions:

[image: browser suggestions]

So in short, when the user clicks on this keychain suggestion, the whole dropdown shuts. This doesn't happen when clicking on any other button within the dropdown as it's not counted as a mouseLeave event!

Answer (score 0):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $(".hover-link,ul").mouseover(function(){
    $(".dropdown").slideDown(300);
    $("li").css("border","2px solid #f4bef2")
    $(".hover-link,ul").mouseleave(function(){
      $(".dropdown").css("display","none");
      $("li").css("border","1px solid #A9A9A9")
    });
  });
});
```

```css
li{
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}
.dropdown{
  height: 30px;
  width: 90px;
  border: 1px solid #A9A9A9;
  background-color: #F2F2F2;
  display:none;
  padding: 25px 50px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav> 
<ul>
 <li><a class="hover-link">Hover Link</a></li>
 
 <div class="dropdown">
   <form class="login-form">
     login form
   </form>
   </ul>
 </div> 
</nav>
```